# Inverse one digit in string with python

Tags: python, string, casting, digit, inverse

I want to inverse a digit in a 3 digit string with Python. 
When I have string like below:

```
000
```

I want to inverse only one from 3 digits at once. So I want to have:

```
100 or 010 or 001
```

I am able to do this with something like:

```
tmp = 000
first = int(not(int(tmp[0]))),tmp[1],tmp[2]
```

And I'm getting:

```
(1, '0', '0') #instead of 100
```

So I guess, I need other casting etc..

Can I do the same in much more efficient and simpler way? This kind of casting is annoying.
Thanks for every idea!

Comment: *to inverse digit* - there would be only inputs with `0` and `1` digits, right?

Comment: Are we talking about *binary* digits? So we can pick a digit ourselves?

Comment: Flipping a bit in an integer is easy; you can use xor `^`. Or are you trying to produce a string? What is your expected input and output?

Comment: @khelwood: based on the code provided by the OP, I think these are stil decimal numbers. But somehow are printed binary.

Comment: Every string is binary digit. I mean we have only 0 and 1 in string.

Comment: @Tatarinho: a *binary* number is still something *different* than a string...

Comment: Yes, I wasn't clear. But still, after changing it has to be string again. You can think about it as the 3 different binary digits in one string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dictionary with the inverse value would work:

```
>>> flip = {'0': '1', '1':'0'}
>>> s = '000'
>>> flip[s[0]] + s[1:]
'100'
>>> s[0] + flip[s[1]] + s[2]
'010'
>>> s[:2] + flip[s[-1]]
'001'
```

Comment: It's the best solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
def inverse(stri,n):
    nums = list(stri)
    if(int(nums[n])==1):
        nums[n] = '0'
    elif(int(nums[n])==0):
        nums[n]= '1'
    else:
        return -1
    return ''.join(map(str,nums))


print inverse('000',2)
```

returns '001'

Answer (score 1):

How about a bitwise OR (|)? I would think it would be faster (at least at a lower level) since this is a basic op that the ALU could do. Then again, with all of the casting and other operations that are going on, it might be a little academic. 
Something like (forgive me, I'm starting to learn Python):

```
>>>tmp = '000'
>>>bit_to_flip = 4
>>>result = int(tmp)|bit_to_flip
>>>formatted_result = "{0:b}".format(result).zfill(len(tmp))
>>>formatted_result
'100'
```

Granted, you need to specify only the decimal value of each binary digit 1,2,4,8,etc...). If you don't want to worry about that, I'd use a dictionary like Mike stated above, except to store the  if at least to make it nice and neat to use (and dictionaries are constant time O(1) ):

```
>>>tmp = '000'
>>>bits_dict = {'1': 1, '2':2, '3':4}
>>>bit_to_flip = '1'
>>>result = int(tmp)|bits_dict[bit_to_flip]
>>>formatted_result = "{0:b}".format(result).zfill(len(tmp))
>>>formatted_result
'001'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option via a list comprehension, which takes a variable `index` to decide which bit to flip.

```
index = 1  # Which bit to flip
flip = {'0': '1', '1':'0'}  # shortcut to flip
''.join([x if i != index else flip[x] for i, x in enumerate(string)])
```

or with the dict inlined:

```
''.join([x if i != index else {'0': '1', '1': '0'}[x] for i, x in enumerate(string)])
```

which can be easily made into a function:

```
def flip(string, index):
    return ''.join([x if i != index else {'0': '1', '1': '0'}[x] for i, x in enumerate(string)])
```